# Mysql time spread

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I have difficulty explaining my question and search for a previous answer. This is my problem -- I have a MySQL table with events

```
CREATE TABLE events {
   id INT,
   event INT,
   date DATETIME
}
```

Data is being added a few times a week or month. I would like to see the statistical spread of time between two adjacent events. Something like:

Time difference between two events

- 1 day appart - 4 occurances
- 2 days apart - 2 occurances
- n days apart - x occurances

It should be something like this, I guess, but calculating the time difference between events.

```
SELECT COUNT('id') AS 'no', ??? AS 'delta' GROUP BY FLOOR( 'delta' )
```

Comment: do a sqlfiddle and show expected results. [What is SQLFiddle and Why Should I Care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of SQL code did it:

```
SET @old = NOW(); 
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `no`, query1.`delta` FROM 
   ( SELECT `id`, `date`, DATEDIFF( @old, `date` ) AS `delta`, @old := `date` AS `old` 
   FROM `life`
   ORDER BY `date`DESC ) query1
GROUP BY `delta`
ORDER BY `delta`
```